# limit collect in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I currently have the following:

```
users = User.all   
comments = users.collect(&:comments)
```

However, if there are thousands of comments, i'd like to only collect 10 from each user to limit the number of database queries that are made. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
users = User.all
comments = users.collect { |user| user.comments.limit(10) }
```

Or with another association in you model :

```
has_many :first_comments, :class_name => "Comment", :limit => 10
```

Then this will result in only two database queries:

```
users = User.includes(:first_comments)
comments = users.collect(&:first_comments)
```

Comment: if you use `flat_map`, `comments` will be a plain array (I guess that's what the OP wants).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
comments = Comment.where(:user_id=>users).limit(10)
```

or

```
comments = Comment.all(:conditions => {:user_id=>users}, :limit => 10)
```

You can use any one that suits you

Comment: users is an array of users that `limit` won't work on. Also I don't want to limit the number of users, I want to limit the number of comments (all the most recent ones)

Comment: That'd be comments for the first 10 users, not 10 comments. .limit(10) needs to come at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest in terms of query looks a little convoluted:

```
Comment.where(["user_id IN (?)", users.collect(&id) ]).limit(10)
```

I presume your sort order is set by a default scope somewhere.

Rails 2:

```
Comment.all(:conditions => ["user_id IN (?)", users.collect(&id) ], :limit => 10)
```

Comment: I've just realised this isn't what you asked for. You asked for 10/user. However that isn't a good way to limit the results, because as users grows so will your output (what happens when you have 5k users). Its far better to limit the final list.

Answer (score 0):

```
users = User.all
comments = Comment.order("DESC created_at").limit(10).all
```

Or, if you only need users for these 10 recent comments, you can try

```
comments = Comment.includes(:users).order("DESC created_at").limit(10).all
users = comments.map(&:user)
```